# Json - Insert a new object between array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a json object , when looped through using a foreach outputs the below :

```
{"Comment": {"id":"1","post_id":"31","created":"14263241"} , "User": {"fname":"Test","lname":"Test2"} } 

{"Comment": {"id":"2","post_id":"32","created":"14263257"} , "User": {"fname":"Lionel","lname":"Messi"} }
```

Where created is a timestamp .

Using a condition from another array , i want to be able to insert a new element in the second array so that it becomes like this :

```
{"Comment": {"id":"2","post_id":"32","created":"14263257"} , "User": {"fname":"Lionel","lname":"Messi"}, "Status":{"status":"add","userid":"10"} }
```

where `"Status":{"status":"add","userid":"10"}` will be from another json object .

Any help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your JSON is on the format

```
var json = [
  {"Comment": {"id":"1","post_id":"31","created":"14263241"} , "User": {"fname":"Test","lname":"Test2"} }, 
  {"Comment": {"id":"2","post_id":"32","created":"14263257"} , "User": {"fname":"Lionel","lname":"Messi"} } 
];
```

And your "another array" holds an item like this

```
var otherJson = {"id":"2", "Status":{"status":"add","userid":"10"} }
```

Then iterate over each element in the first `json` and insert `Status` from `otherJson` when the criteria match :

```
for (var index in json) {
    if (json[index].Comment.id == otherJson.id) {
        json[index].Status = otherJson.Status;
    }      
}
```

The item with the `Comment.id` `2` is now enriched with `Status`.